# List of terminal generated signals (eg Ctrl-C -> SIGINT)

Tags: terminal, keyboard, signals

Where can I find a complete list of the keyboard combinations which send  signals in Linux?

Eg:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - SIGINT
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - SIGQUIT

Comment: The "keyboard" doesn't send any signals, the line discipline does.  Find out what a line discipline is, then read `man 1 stty`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura The line discipline is kind of a keyboard driver.

Comment: @Gilles Not really.  The keyboard driver deals with scancodes and the like.  The line discipline is a sort of higher level glue that gives the application an unified view over many other things, like modem lines, USB-to-serial adapters, HID devices, etc.

Comment: @SatoKatsura It's a part of the operating system that sits beween the application and the keyboard. In other words, it's part of the keyboard driver. With a hardware terminal (like a vt100), it's the only transformation of keyboard input that's done by the computer as opposed to the terminal itself.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The Linux N_TTY line discipline only sends three different signals: SIGINT, SIGQUIT, and SIGTSTP. By default the following control characters produce the signals:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - SIGINT
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - SIGQUIT
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - SIGTSTP

Comment: Hmm, what about Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: No signals are involved when you press Ctrl-S or Ctrl-Q. They just throttle the flow of characters, preventing them from reaching the consuming process. Eventually, when buffers fill up, the producing process will block in the write system call until Ctrl-Q unthrottles the flow. Note that it is normal for the call to write can block even without Ctrl-S: if the receiving process is slow to consume the data sent to it, e.g. because it is spending most of its time processing already received data instead of reading new data.

Comment: `man stty | grep -C1 signal` is one source for these three being the only signals generated by the terminal.

Comment: @TomHale ... Except "modem control signals" are electrical signals. :) Really, `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT` and `SIGTSTP` are the only "usual" signals sent by the line discipline. On BSD you also have things like `SIGINFO`, but that's not standard.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `stty` to check or change the characters that generate signals.

```
$ stty -a | grep -Ewoe '(intr|quit|susp) = [^;]+'
intr = ^C
quit = ^\
susp = ^Z
```

`intr` (interrupt) generates `SIGINT`, `quit` generates `SIGQUIT`, `susp` (suspend) generates `SIGTSTP`. `stty -a` will also show things like `start = ^Q; stop = ^S;` and `erase = ^?` (backspace), which don't send signals but affect the terminal layer otherwise.

Plain `stty` will show the non-default settings and e.g. `stty intr ^Q` would change the interrupt character to `^Q` instead of `^C`.

I think `^L` (form feed, new page) is not a terminal feature, but a character often used by applications to ask for a redraw the view, rechecking the window size at the same time.

Comment: `^L` has a different meaning for different applications.  In most `curses`-based applications (such as `vim`, `less`, `mutt`, `mc`, etc.) it forces a complete redraw (thus re-checking the window size), but in shells (`bash` etc.) it just clears the screen.  There is no `SIGWINCH` involved.