# Why does su command ignore SIGSTOP?

Tags: linux, terminal, signals, su, sigkill

After entering `su` when I prompted to enter a password:

```
user@debian:~$ su
Password:
```

I can't send `SIGSTOP` (`ctrl+Z`) from my keyboard (the same terminal) - nothing happens. So the only way to exit is to type some (right or wrong) password. Why can't I suspend `su` such a way?

UPD: It seems that `ctrl+Z` is queued. Thus when sending `ctrl+Z` - nothing happens, but then after typing `Enter` signal arrives and `su` becomes stopped. Still can't understand such behavior. Is this standard behavior for all Unix-like or just Linux?

Comment: How do you send `SIGSTOP` and/or `SIGKILL` ?

Comment: @schaiba `ctrl+Z` and `ctrl+C` - the only way I know to send signals from terminal to running (in this terminal) task.

Comment: `ctrl-C` is not `SIGKILL`. it's usually `SIGINT`. And any process can ignore `SIGINT`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed. But what about `SIGSTOP` through `ctrl+Z`?

Comment: `su` is a setuid program that runs as root. You do not have privileges to kill a process owned by another user, even if it's running inside your terminal window. See the [kill(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) man page for a more technical explanation.

Comment: @z0lupka `ctrl-Z` is usually `SIGSTSP` - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362559/list-of-terminal-generated-signals-eg-ctrl-c-sigint

Comment: @doneal24 That can get a bit complex with setuid programs, as the effective and real uid's do give the uid that started the process some permissions.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1059998/dont-allow-user-to-kill-program-started-as-another-user-using-setuid-bit for killing a process Read the **RATIONALE** section on [the POSIX `setuid()` page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html) for some background.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it appears you've got an all the details for an answer in your comment thread, are you going to turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear up some basic errors:

1. The signal *is not* queued.  Queueing is a specific thing when it comes to signals, and does not happen with this particular signal.  The signal is *masked*.
2. This particular signal *is not* `SIGSTOP`.  The `susp` character causes the line discipline to send a `SIGTSTP`.

As with so many things that contradict the 1980s view of the `login` and `su` commands, the root of the behaviour here is PAM.

It's not `su` doing this.  And it does not happen on operating systems other than those using the *Linux PAM* library.  It does not happen on the BSDs using the OpenPAM library, for example.

It is the Linux PAM provided PAM module named `pam_unix` doing this.  More specifically, it is the library-supplied default "conversation" function `misc_conv()`, called inside the `pam_unix` code, that is doing this.  It specifically masks `SIGTSTP` whilst it is prompting for an item of input, [ostensibly so that the library can clean up](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/libpam_misc/misc_conv.c#L152).  This is why the signal is not delivered until the input has been entered.

OpenPAM supplies a `pam_unix` PAM module too.  This calls the OpenPAM library-supplied default "conversation" function `openpam_ttyconv()`.  That latter [does not mask signals](https://www.openpam.org/browser/openpam/trunk/lib/libpam/openpam_ttyconv.c#L119).  No-one seems to have noticed that one can suspend `su` at the password prompt on FreeBSD et al. and the terminal will be left with echo turned off.  This is possibly because the operating-system-supplied command-line shells on FreeBSD all have line editing libraries, which immediately re-adjust terminal settings when they take over to prompt for input and do their own echoing anyway.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014).  ["PAM changed everything, over two decades ago."](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html#PAM). *Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561459/5132
- https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243584